# How to Set Custom Suffix with Large Value Formatter

Tags: java, android, largenumber

I want to set custom suffix with Large Value Formatter. It's default suffix was :

- k for thousand
- m for million
- b for billion
- t for trillion

but i want to make it custom as :

- rb for thousand
- jt for million
- m for billion
- t for trillion

i've been tried to change it's default it to rb, jt, m and t but the result was just :

- r for thousand, not rb
- j for million, not jt

and it's got no probs with m and t as it only contains 1 suffix

```
private String[] mSuffix = new String[]{"", "k", "m", "b", "t"};
```

the result was :
812k,
8.12m,
8.12b,
8.12t

tried to change it to:

```
private String[] mSuffix = new String[]{"", "rb", "jt", "m", "t"};
```

the result was :
812r, 
8.12j,
8.12m,
8.12t

and this is when the mSuffix is used

```
 private String makePretty(double number) {

    String r = mFormat.format(number);

    int numericValue1 = Character.getNumericValue(r.charAt(r.length() - 1));
    int numericValue2 = Character.getNumericValue(r.charAt(r.length() - 2));
    int combined = Integer.valueOf(numericValue2 + "" + numericValue1);

    r = r.replaceAll("E[0-9][0-9]", mSuffix[combined / 3]);

    while (r.length() > mMaxLength || r.matches("[0-9]+\\.[a-z]")) {
        r = r.substring(0, r.length() - 2) + r.substring(r.length() - 1);
    }

    return r;
}
```

I expect the output was

- 812rb,
- 8.12jt,
- 8.12m,
- 8.12t

Thanks in advance

Comment: If all you want to do is change the names of the fields you could just `String.replace()` after the formatter does its job. Should just be a string replacement:  `formatted.replace("k", "rb") or formatted.replace("m", "jt") or formatted("b", "m")`

Comment: thanks for the advice but i just dont get it, where should i placed formatted.replace ("k", "rb")

Comment: because it's an array so it cant be just replace through that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `mFormat.formatter(number);` does the right thing (5000.0 -> "5k"), then:

```
private String makePretty(double number) {

  String r = mFormat.format(number);

  if (r.indexOf("k") > 0) {
    r = r.replace("k", "rb");
  } else if (r.indexOf("m") > 0) {
    r = r.replace("m", "jt");
  } else if (r.indexOf("b") > 0) {
    r = r.replace("b", "m")
  }

  return r;
}
```